# Convert Redis ByteString to BasicDBObject

Tags: java, mongodb, redis

I need to convert serialized Java Object (get from Redis) to a Java model that extends com.mongodb.BasicDBObject (mongo-java-driver).

```
class Member extends BasicDBObject {
    public Member(DBObject doc) {
        super(doc.toMap());
    }
    public Member(BasicDBObject doc) {
        super(doc);
    }
    ...
}
```

What I got from Redis is in ByteString form.

In summary, I need to convert ByteString -> BasicDBObject

Answer (score 1):

You should use an intermediate model to persist your model. MongoDB's `BasicDBObject`s base on `LinkedHashMap`, but there is a good chance, that you end up with internal data structures that are not Java-serializable.

Neither `DBObject` nor `BSONObject` extend `Serializable`. I propose that you store JSON within Redis. A shortcut could be storing BSON instead of JSON within Redis (see `BasicBSONEncoder#encode` and `BasicBSONDecoder#readObject`).

Answer (score 0):

@mp911de You are right. The good thing is that DBObject and BSONObject do not extend Serializable. In other words, there is no need to write a deserializer for DBObject/BSONObject. I found a solution:

ByteString from Redis -> byte array -> Object -> cast to my class Member.